# Dart Flutter : How to run animation from a scoped-model?

Tags: flutter, scoped-model

How to run animation in a widget which is a ScopedModeldescendant, from the scoped-model. I have a red button here which when clicked shows a square. The square is made to disappear after 3 seconds, which happens to quickly. What I want to do is make the square fade away in a few seconds. I tried AnimationController but it requires a 'vsync:' parameter which I've seen is usually done in an initState() as 'vsync: this' and gives an error when used elsewhere.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'scoped model Opacity',
      home: new ScopedModel<MyScopedModel>(
        model: new MyScopedModel(),
        child: new MyPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScopedModel extends Model {
  double myOpacity = 0.0;
  Timer myTimer;

  AnimationController myAnimationController;

  void myShowSquare() {
    myOpacity = 1.0;
    myTimer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 3), _removeSquare);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _removeSquare() {
    myOpacity = 0.0;
    myTimer.cancel();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: new ScopedModelDescendant<MyScopedModel>(
          builder: (context, child, model) => new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: model.myShowSquare,
                    child: new Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(
                              width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                          color: Colors.deepOrange,
                        ),
                        new Text(
                          '+',
                          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Opacity(
                    opacity: model.myOpacity,
                    child: new Container(
                      constraints:
                          new BoxConstraints.expand(width: 50.0, 
                                height: 50.0),
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is a [FadeTransition](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeTransition-class.html) which I believe handles the hard work for you of fading your widget out. You could also potentially use the [AnimatedCrossFade](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html) widget if you want to change sizes as well.

However, if you're looking to animate things yourself I'd advise looking at the [Animation documentation](https://flutter.io/animations/) and this [Animation Tutorial](https://flutter.io/tutorials/animation/) as they will explain the details of how it works.

Comment: I can use FadeTransition and I also plan to do other types of animations. Well I think I'II have to read up on the Animation tutorials. Thanks. I was looking if it was possible to implement the TickerProvider abstract class.

Comment: If you extend the SingleTickerProviderStateMixin it makes your widget class a ticker provider. I believe that whichever widget is the ticker provider should contain the entire animation for performance reasons

Comment: I reached up to making the model class a TickerProvider with the 'implements TickerProvider' and I had to @override Ticker createTicker(TickerCallback onTick) {
    // TODO: implement createTicker
  } and this is where I am lost. The documentation is of no help. I think I'II go with your suggestion of extending the widget class with the TickerProviderStatemixin.

Comment: The simple answer to that is to create a `new Ticker()` and return it, but using the SingleTickerProviderStateMixin should do what you need and handles things like saving & disposing of the Ticker at the proper times. The [SingleTickerProviderStateMixin source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart) might help you understand what they're doing there.